# Need to Get Checkbox value in AngularJS Controller, But Initially need checkbox to set to [Checked]

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

### My front code for checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" ng-model="chkActive" ng-init="chkActive='true'" runat="server" Text="Active" Checked="true" />
```

### My AngularJS Controller Code:

```
var _master = {
   UnitCode: $scope.unitCode,
   UnitName: $scope.unitName,
   chkActive: $scope.chkActive
};
```

I need to get checkbox value in above chkActive variable, bu I can get.
Help me to solve this problem in such easy ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use `ng-checked` to set checkbox checked? And call `ngClick` function to set the checkbox value to `_master` variable

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" ng-model="chkActive" ng-init="chkActive='true'" runat="server" Text="Active" ng-checked="chkActive" ng-click="clCheck()" />

$scope.clCheck = function(){
   var _master.chkActive = $scope.chkActive 
}
```

Comment: I need to get Checkbox value in ASP.NET WebMethod, but it still showing false after applying this method

Comment: Thanks now its working, I was making mistake, Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ng-checked` to achieve that.

Like this example:

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Padre1Controller', function($scope){    
    $scope.myvalue = true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Padre1Controller">
        ng-checked :<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="myvalue"><br/>
        <pre>{{myvalue}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```